# No puedo escribir en un input dentro de una tabla en ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tratando de colocar varios `input` dentro de una tabla, me he encontrado con un inconveniente, el cual es que no me permite escribir nada en estos, por mas que haga cosas.

Según leí en mi búsqueda, no puede colocarse de tal forma.

#### Estado

```
this.state = { 
            energiaConsumida:{
                enero:"",
                febrero:"",
                marzo:"",
                abril:"",
                mayo:"",
                junio:"",
                julio:"",
                agosto:"",
                septiembre:"",
                octubre:"",
                noviembre:"",
                diciembre:""
            },
}
```

#### Dentro de la tabla

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" 
        placeholder="Enero"
        value={this.state.energiaConsumida.enero}
        onChange={this.updateFields.bind(this, 'consumoEnero')}
        name="consumoEnero"
        maxLength="4"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

#### funcion para actualizar los inputs

```
updateFields(propertyName, event) {
    let energyData = this.state.energiaConsumida;
    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
    if (event.target.value == '' || re.test(event.target.value)) {    
        energyData[propertyName] = event.target.value;        
        this.setState({ energiaConsumida: energyData }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema es que no estás escribiendo en el state que toma el value del input, si pones `onChange={this.updateFields.bind(this, 'enero')}`, ya debe poner un valor en el input

Comment: Lo estás haciendo con ES6? Podrás compartir un poco más de lo que estás haciendo en ese componente?

Comment: @KacosPro ya mismo puse a compilar, probando y te digo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás tratando de escribir en `this.state.energiaConsumida.consumoEnero` y el valor del input lo toma de `this.state.energiaConsumida.enero`.

Cambia tu parámetro `consumoEnero` por `enero`

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="Enero" 
  value={this.state.energiaConsumida.enero} 
  onChange={this.updateFields.bind(this, 'enero')} 
  name="consumoEnero"
  maxLength="4" />
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfecto.